# How can I verify that a field has no value (null)?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

How can I check if a certain field has no value (`null`) using Selenium Web Driver?

This is what I have so far:

```
WebDriverWait wait5 = new WebDriverWait(driver, 5);
wait5.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.name("chargeId")));
```

Comment: Code you have added is doing completely different thing. It waits till element become *clickable*. Which field you want to verify?

Comment: `null` **is not the same as having no value**. What kind of element is it? Show us the HTML of it.

Answer (score 0):

```
WebDriverWait wait5 = new WebDriverWait(driver, 5);
WebElement charge = wait5.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.name("chargeId")));
boolean noChargeIdPresent = charge.getText().isEmpty();
```

This will let you know whether the field is empty.

Comment: No it wont, `WebdriverWait` dont have `getText` method, I guess you want to use `WebElement` instead

Comment: Lol, good point. I completely glossed over that. :p I modified to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

```
WebDriverWait wait5 = new WebDriverWait(driver, 5);
wait5.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.name("chargeId")));
if(wait5.findElement(By.name("chargeId")).getText().length() == 0) {
      // =========== DO WHAT YOU WANT IF EMPTY============
}
else {
     //======== DO WHEN NOT EMPTY==================
}
```